# Notepad++ - How to use "Operators2"?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

In the "*Define your language...*" settings, tab "*Operators & Delimiters*" there's a field called "*Operators2 (separators required)*".

Firstly, I don't know what "separators required" means in that term.

Secondly, whatever I typed in there, it had no effect on the syntax highlighting.

And thirdly, could you please take a look here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747390/notepad-how-to-get-different-syntax-highlighting-in-a-string-without-spaces

That question is sort of important to my current work and it hasn't been answered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Operators2* matches words (the mentioned separators being whitespace delimiters), *Operators1* is a sub-string match.

If `OR` was in Operators1:

X = APPLES **OR** **OR** ANGES

Which is wrong in the case of `ORANGES`, Operators2 allows you to:

X = APPLES **OR** ORANGES

Comment: I see, thanks. But I guess I can't use different highlightings for them, can I? (I've seen no option)

Comment: No, I think the single *styler* button applies to both Operator groups